# Problemas al editar una linea Laravel

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel-5, postgresql

de antemano gracias por leer, y espero si no e smucha molestia me pudieran guiar para poder solucionar este problema.

Tengo un formulario que se llama servidor, en ese formulario yo ingreso los datos importantes, entre ellos El servidor y la version que tiene.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El primer campo me trae los sistemas operativos, y a partir del sistema que se escoja, el segundo campo me lista las versiones de ese sistema.

hasta ese punto todo bien

El problema viene, cuando quiero editar un servidor que ya tengo inscrito, porque, lamentablemente, no me carga la version del sistema operativo almacenado anteriormente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Este es el codigo del mi form, me toco poner la version de esa manera, puesto que si lo ponia con el {!! Form que utilice para el campo sistema operativo, no me funcionaba el ajax que cree para que me funcionara como lo necesitaba(Que el campo version, se llene de acuerdo al sistema operativo que escoja).

ELEMENTO PADRE:

```
 {!! Form::mySelect('id_so', 'Sistema Operativo: ', App\SistemasOperativos::pluck('nombre', 'id')->toArray(), null, ['id' => 'so', 'class'=>'chosen', 'placeholder' => 'Escoge una opción']) !!}
```

ELEMENTO HIJO

```
            <br>
          <label class="chosen" for="nombre">Version Sistema operativo</label>
          <br>
            <select name="id_version" id="version" style="width: 100%">
               <option value="">Selecciona un sistema operativo primero</option>
            </select>
          <br>
```

Este es el ajax

```
<script> 
    var rutaConsulta = "{{ route('admin.ruta.consulta.so') }}"; 
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
    selectChange(); 
    }); 

    function selectChange(){ 
    $('#so').on('change', function(e){ 
    var idSo = $(this).val(); 
    ajaxSelect(idSo); 
    }); 
    } 

    function ajaxSelect(id)
    { 
        $.ajax({ 
        type: 'POST', 
        headers: { 
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') 
        },   
        url: rutaConsulta, 
        data: {id: id}, 
        dataType: 'json', 
        beforeSend: function(){ 
        } 
        }).done(function(response) { 
        var html = '<option value="">Selecciona una opción</option>'; 
        $.each(response.versiones, function(i, elem){ 
        html += '<option value="'+ elem.id +'">'+ elem.version +'</option>' 
        }); 
        $('#version').html(html); 
        }).fail(function(data) { 

        }); 
    }
</script>
```

Este es el controlador ....

```
  public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {

        $item = Servidores::findOrFail($id);
        $item->update($request->all());
        //return back()->withSuccess(trans('app.success_update'));
        return redirect()->route(ADMIN.'.servidoresRoute.index')->withSuccess(trans('app.success_update'));
    }

public function edit($id)
{
    $item = Servidores::findOrFail($id);
    return view('admin.servidoresVistas.edit', compact('item'));
}

public function index()
{
    $items = Servidores::with('parentServidores','servidores2','roles','so','versionn','marcas','modelos','tipos','estados','usos')->get();

    return view('admin.servidoresVistas.index', compact('items'));
}


public function consultarVersiones(Request $request)
{
   $id_so = $request->id;
   $versiones = SoVersiones::where('id_so', $id_so)->get();

   $respuesta = array();
   $respuesta['versiones'] = $versiones->toArray();   
   return response()->json($respuesta);
}


public function consultarModelos(Request $request) 
{ 
    $id_marca = $request->id; 
    $modelos = Modelos::where('id_marca', $id_marca)->get(); 


    $respuesta = array(); 
    $respuesta['modelos'] = $modelos->toArray(); 
    return response()->json($respuesta); 
}



 /**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
   $sistemas = SistemasOperativos::orderBy('nombre','asc')->get();
   $marcas = Marcas::orderBy('nombre','asc')->get();  
   return view ('admin.servidoresVistas.create', compact('sistemas','marcas'));
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    Servidores::create($request->all());

    //return back()->withSuccess(trans('app.success_store'));
    return redirect()->route(ADMIN.'.servidoresRoute.index')->withSuccess(trans('app.success_store'));

}
```

Si pongo el campo version de esta manera

```
{!! Form::mySelect('id_version', 'Version: ', App\SoVersiones::pluck('version', 'id')->toArray(), null, ['id' => 'version', 'class'=>'chosen', 'placeholder' => 'Escoge una opción']) !!}
```

Si me trae la versión, pero no me funciona el ajax

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ojala me pudieran ayudar, ya le he dado mil vueltas y me tiene estancado este tema,

Les agradezco por leer.

edit:

Esta es toda la pagina

```
<?php $title = isset($item) ? $item->name: "Agregar nuevo Servidor" ?>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

{!! Form::myInput('text', 'hostname', 'Hostname', ['required']) !!}
{!! Form::myInput('text', 'ip', 'IP', ['required']) !!}
{!! Form::myInput('text', 'cpu', 'CPU', ['required']) !!}
{!! Form::myInput('number', 'cores', 'Cores', ['required']) !!}
{!! Form::myInput('number', 'ram', 'Ram (MB)', ['required']) !!}
{!! Form::myInput('number', 'disco', 'Disco (GB)', ['required']) !!}
{!! Form::mySelect('id_rol', 'Rol', App\Roles::pluck('nombre', 'id')->toArray(), null, ['class'=>'chosen', 'placeholder' => 'Escoge una opción']) !!}






<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="box" style="border:1px solid #d2d6de;">
      <div class="box-body" style="margin:10px;">

          {!! Form::mySelect('id_so', 'Sistema Operativo: ', App\SistemasOperativos::pluck('nombre', 'id')->toArray(), null, ['id' => 'so', 'class'=>'chosen', 'placeholder' => 'Escoge una opción']) !!}

            <br>
          <label class="chosen" for="nombre">Version Sistema operativo</label>
          <br>
            <select name="id_version" id="version" style="width: 100%">
               <option value="">Selecciona un sistema operativo primero</option>
            </select>
          <br>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


           {!! Form::mySelect('id_version', 'Version: ', App\SoVersiones::pluck('version', 'id')->toArray(), null, ['id' => 'version', 'class'=>'chosen', 'placeholder' => 'Escoge una opción']) !!}


    <script> 
        var rutaConsulta = "{{ route('admin.ruta.consulta.so') }}"; 
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
        selectChange(); 
        }); 

        function selectChange(){ 
        $('#so').on('change', function(e){ 
        var idSo = $(this).val(); 
        ajaxSelect(idSo); 
        }); 
        } 

        function ajaxSelect(id)
        { 
            $.ajax({ 
            type: 'POST', 
            headers: { 
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') 
            },   
            url: rutaConsulta, 
            data: {id: id}, 
            dataType: 'json', 
            beforeSend: function(){ 
            } 
            }).done(function(response) { 
            var html = '<option value="">Selecciona una opción</option>'; 
            $.each(response.versiones, function(i, elem){ 
            html += '<option value="'+ elem.id +'">'+ elem.version +'</option>' 
            }); 
            $('#version').html(html); 
            }).fail(function(data) { 

            }); 
        }
    </script>

{!! Form::mySelect('id_tipo', 'Tipo', App\Tipos::pluck('nombre', 'id')->toArray(), null, ['required','class'=>'chosen', 'placeholder' => 'Escoge una opción']) !!}

{!! Form::mySelect('id_uso', 'Uso', App\Usos::pluck('nombre', 'id')->toArray(), null, ['required','id' => 'listaUsos', 'class'=>'chosen', 'placeholder' => 'Escoge una opción']) !!}

<div class="requerido-con-virtual">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="box" style="border:1px solid #d2d6de;">
        <div class="box-body" style="margin:10px;">

{!! Form::mySelect('id_padre', 
               'Servidor padre:', 
                App\Servidores::select(DB::raw("ip AS ip"), "id")->where('id_uso', '=', 1)-> pluck('ip', 'id')->toArray(),       
                null, 
               ['class'=>'requerido-con-virtual', 'style' => 'width: 100%;', 'placeholder' => 'Escoge una opción']) !!}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- MARCA Y MODELO -->

<div class="requerido-con-fisico">

        <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="box" style="border:1px solid #d2d6de;">
            <div class="box-body" style="margin:10px;">


              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <div class="box" style="border:1px solid #d2d6de;">
                    <div class="box-body" style="margin:10px;">

                        {!! Form::mySelect('id_marca', 'Marca: ', App\Marcas::pluck('nombre', 'id')->toArray(), null, ['id' => 'marca', 'class'=>'chosen', 'placeholder' => 'Escoge una opción']) !!}

                    <label class="col-sm-5" for="nombre">Modelo</label>
                    <select name="id_modelo" id="modelo" style="width: 100%"> 
                    <option value="70" name=id_modelo>Selecciona un modelo primero</option> 
                    </select>

                    <br>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

                    <script> 
                      var rutaConsulta2 = "{{ route('admin.ruta.consulta.mod') }}"; 
                      $(document).ready(function(){ 
                      selectChange2(); 
                      }); 

                      function selectChange2(){ 

                        $('#marca').on('change', function(e){ 
                        var idMarca = $(this).val(); 
                        ajaxSelect1(idMarca); 
                        }); 
                        } 

                      function ajaxSelect1(id){ 
                        $.ajax({ 
                        type: 'POST', 
                        headers: { 
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') 
                        } ,
                        url:  rutaConsulta2, 
                        data: {id: id}, 
                        dataType: 'json', 
                        beforeSend: function(){ 
                        } 
                        }).done(function(response) { 
                        var html = '<option value="">Selecciona una opción</option>'; 
                        $.each(response.modelos, function(i, elem){ 
                        html += '<option value="'+ elem.id +'">'+ elem.modelo +'</option>' 
                        }); 
                        $('#modelo').html(html); 
                        }).fail(function(data) { 

                        }); 
                        }
                    </script>

                {!! Form::myInput('text', 'mac', 'Mac: ', ['class' => 'requerido-con-fisico', 'style' => 'width: 100%;']) !!}
                {!! Form::myInput('text', 'serial', 'Serial: ', ['class' => 'requerido-con-fisico', 'style' => 'width: 100%;']) !!}
                {!! Form::mySelect('ubicacion', 'Ubicación: ', config('variables.ubicacion')) !!}
                {!! Form::myInput('text', 'propietario', 'Propietario: ', ['class' => 'requerido-con-fisico', 'style' => 'width: 100%;']) !!}

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

{!! Form::mySelect('id_estado', 'Estado', App\Estados::pluck('nombre', 'id')->toArray(), null, ['class'=>'chosen', 'placeholder' => 'Escoge una opción']) !!}

{!! Form::myInput('text', 'observacion', 'Observacion', ['required']) !!}


 <script>
     $(function() 
      {
      $("#listaUsos").change(function()
        {
          if($("option:selected", this).text() == 'Fisico')
          {
              $(".requerido-con-fisico").show();
              $(".requerido-con-virtual").hide();
            }
            else
            {
              $(".requerido-con-fisico").hide();
              $(".requerido-con-virtual").show();                
            }
        });
      });
  </script>
```

Comment: checa si realmente te arroja la lista de las versiones del sisfema al momento de editar

Comment: Osea, si cambio el sistema, efectivamente me cambian las nuevas versiones, pero no me cargan las que traen por defecto desde la base.

Comment: esto es de una misma universidad o como?
 creo que respondi esta misma pregunta hace un tiempo atras!

Comment: Jajaja, No creo, si no, seguramente te recordaria, pero si he hecho varias preguntas sobre este proyecto que estoy haciendo.

Comment: puedes indicarme cual es el elemento padre donde estan todos encerrados para mejorte ya del todo tu codigo

Comment: Listo, lo voy a agregar en el post.

Comment: El elemento padre donde estan encerrados todos se llama Servidor, Quieres que agrege el modelo y el controlador de ellos ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi e implemente algunas mejoras solamente:

```
var rutaConsulta = "{{ route('admin.ruta.consulta.so') }}";

$(document).ready(function() {

    function _ajax(url, data) {
        var response = $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
                url: url,
                data: data,
                dataType: 'json'
            })
            .fail(function(data) {
                alert(`ups errror ${data}`);
            });
        return response;
    }

    $('.box-body').on('change', 'select[id="version"]', function(e) {
         let element = "#version";
        _ajax(rutaConsulta, { "id": $(this).val() }).done(function(response) {

            var html = '<option value="">Selecciona una opción</option>';

            $.each(response.versiones, function(i, elem) {
                html += '<option value="' + elem.id + '">' + elem.version + '</option>'
            });
            $(element).html(html);
        });
    });


    $('.box-body').on('change', 'select[id="marca"]', function(e) {
        element = "#version";
        _ajax(rutaConsulta, { "id": $(this).val() }).done(function(response) {

            var html = '<option value="">Selecciona una opción</option>';
            $.each(response.versiones, function(i, elem) {
                html += '<option value="' + elem.id + '">' + elem.version + '</option>'
            });
            $(element).html(html);
        });
    });

});
```

**explicacion:**

**esto es con ayuda de jquery event delegation:**
[jquery event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
al ser elementos que se cargan dinamicamente no estan el doom al cargar la pagina por primera ves asi que si intentamos hacer esto: `$("element")` simplemente no los encontrar con event delegatin lo que hacemos es que le decimo que vuelva a leer el documento a partir del padre que existe desde que carga el dom `$("elemento_padre")` en busca de nuevos hijos:

```
$("elemento_padre").on("change" ,"elemento_hijo",function(e){ console.log(e.target)});
```

ahora para especificar lo que seleccionaremos mas claro le decimos que el hijo que queremos debe ser un select con id="x" gracias al selecto de attributos:
[selector de attributos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Selectores_atributo)
que nos permite hacer esto `select[id="version"]`

Comment: Permiteme probar, que pena la demora, es que me ocupe un poco.

Comment: Amigo, no entiendo bien esta la parte del jquery event delegation. Me podrias ayudar por favor.

Comment: event delegation lo que hace es re -leer el documento es decir buscas un elemento estatico que se carge desde el principio ejemplo: `$("document")` el documento siempre carga al principio o el `$("body")` apartir de hay empezara a leer el documento para ver los cambios.... en este caso como usas ajax estos elementos no existian en principio asi que le dices buscame `$(" .box-body")` captura el evento `change`  pero no el tuyo el de tu tu hijo `select[id="marca"]` y ejecuta un callback; que seria `$(".box-body").("change",'select[id="marca"]',function(e){` ahora esta mas claro?

Comment: En teoria si lo entiendo totalmente, Esperame haber si lo puedo implementar tal cual me lo indicas en mi codigo, y te aviso. (Perdón por la demora en responder).